# Why can not I change the active class after loading the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my code

```js
$('.btn-toggle').click(function() {
  if ($('.btn-toggle').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.report-action-btn').css('opacity', '1');
  } else {
    $('report-action-btn').css('opacity', '0');
  }

  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
/**** Toggle button ****/

.btn-toggle {
  margin: 0 4rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  color: #6b7381;
  background: #bdc1c8;
}

.btn-toggle:focus,
.btn-toggle.focus,
.btn-toggle:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle:before,
.btn-toggle:after {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  width: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}


/*.btn-toggle:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: -4rem;
}*/


/*.btn-toggle:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: -4rem;
  opacity: .5;
}*/

.btn-toggle>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1875rem;
  left: 0.1875rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 1.125rem;
  border-radius: 1.125rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.active>.handle {
  left: 1.6875rem;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.active:before {
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: -0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .75px;
  left: 0.4125rem;
  width: 2.325rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle:before,
.btn-toggle:after {
  color: #6b7381;
}

.btn-toggle.active {
  background-color: #29b5a8;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg:focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:after {
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}


/*.btn-toggle.btn-lg:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: -5rem;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: -5rem;
  opacity: .5;
}*/

.btn-toggle.btn-lg>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3125rem;
  left: 0.3125rem;
  width: 1.875rem;
  height: 1.875rem;
  border-radius: 1.875rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active>.handle {
  left: 2.8125rem;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active:before {
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: 0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .75px;
  left: 0.6875rem;
  width: 3.875rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm {
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  width: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.55rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: -0.5rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: -0.5rem;
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1875rem;
  left: 0.1875rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 1.125rem;
  border-radius: 1.125rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active>.handle {
  left: 1.6875rem;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: -0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .75px;
  left: 0.4125rem;
  width: 2.325rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs:after {
  line-height: 1rem;
  width: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: 0;
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.125rem;
  left: 0.125rem;
  width: 0.75rem;
  height: 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active>.handle {
  left: 1.125rem;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active:before {
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: -1rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .75px;
  left: 0.275rem;
  width: 1.55rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary {
  color: #6b7381;
  background: #bdc1c8;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-secondary:after {
  color: #6b7381;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary.active {
  background-color: #ff8300;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary.active {
  background-color: #ff8300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="report-sens-btn btn btn-lg btn-toggle" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="true" autocomplete="off">
<div class="handle"></div>
</button>

<a class="report-action-btn btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-success m-b-5">
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
</a>
```

I want when toggle button has `.active` class, `<a>` tag be `opacity:1` else be `opacity:0` 
The problem here is when the page loads and the button is clicked to become active the button does not recognize the active class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will work fine for you:**

*Just Add below code for click on page load.*

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.btn-toggle').trigger('click');
});
```

*and to toggle the opacity of `.report-action-btn` you can use `CSS` its better that way:*

```
.report-action-btn{
  opacity:0;
  background: red;/*remove this only for test*/
  display: inline-block;/*remove this only for test*/
  width: 10px;/*remove this only for test*/
  height: 10px;/*remove this only for test*/
}

.btn-toggle.active+.report-action-btn{
  opacity:1;
}
```

Here am putting a working sample for you.

```js
$('.btn-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(window).load(function() {
  $('.btn-toggle').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
/**** Toggle button ****/

.btn-toggle {
  margin: 0 4rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  color: #6b7381;
  background: #bdc1c8;
}

.btn-toggle:focus,
.btn-toggle.focus,
.btn-toggle:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle:before,
.btn-toggle:after {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  width: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}


/*.btn-toggle:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: -4rem;
}*/


/*.btn-toggle:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: -4rem;
  opacity: .5;
}*/

.btn-toggle>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1875rem;
  left: 0.1875rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 1.125rem;
  border-radius: 1.125rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.active>.handle {
  left: 1.6875rem;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.active:before {
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: -0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .75px;
  left: 0.4125rem;
  width: 2.325rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle:before,
.btn-toggle:after {
  color: #6b7381;
}

.btn-toggle.active {
  background-color: #29b5a8;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg:focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:after {
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}


/*.btn-toggle.btn-lg:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: -5rem;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: -5rem;
  opacity: .5;
}*/

.btn-toggle.btn-lg>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3125rem;
  left: 0.3125rem;
  width: 1.875rem;
  height: 1.875rem;
  border-radius: 1.875rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active>.handle {
  left: 2.8125rem;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active:before {
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: 0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .75px;
  left: 0.6875rem;
  width: 3.875rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm {
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  width: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.55rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: -0.5rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: -0.5rem;
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1875rem;
  left: 0.1875rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 1.125rem;
  border-radius: 1.125rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active>.handle {
  left: 1.6875rem;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: -0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .75px;
  left: 0.4125rem;
  width: 2.325rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs:after {
  line-height: 1rem;
  width: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: 0;
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.125rem;
  left: 0.125rem;
  width: 0.75rem;
  height: 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active>.handle {
  left: 1.125rem;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active:before {
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: -1rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .75px;
  left: 0.275rem;
  width: 1.55rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary {
  color: #6b7381;
  background: #bdc1c8;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-secondary:after {
  color: #6b7381;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary.active {
  background-color: #ff8300;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary.active {
  background-color: #ff8300;
}

.report-action-btn{
  opacity:0;
  background: red;/*remove this only for test*/
  display: inline-block;/*remove this only for test*/
  width: 10px;/*remove this only for test*/
  height: 10px;/*remove this only for test*/
}

.btn-toggle.active+.report-action-btn{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="report-sens-btn btn btn-lg btn-toggle" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="true" autocomplete="off">
<div class="handle"></div>
</button>

<a class="report-action-btn btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-success m-b-5">
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
</a>
```

Hope this was helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Manually call the click event

```js
$('.btn-toggle').click(function() {
  if ($('.btn-toggle').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.report-action-btn').css('opacity', '1');
  } else {
    $('report-action-btn').css('opacity', '0');
  }

  $(this).toggleClass('active');
}).click();
```

```css
/**** Toggle button ****/

.btn-toggle {
  margin: 0 4rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  color: #6b7381;
  background: #bdc1c8;
}

.btn-toggle:focus,
.btn-toggle.focus,
.btn-toggle:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle:before,
.btn-toggle:after {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  width: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}


/*.btn-toggle:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: -4rem;
}*/


/*.btn-toggle:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: -4rem;
  opacity: .5;
}*/

.btn-toggle>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1875rem;
  left: 0.1875rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 1.125rem;
  border-radius: 1.125rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.active>.handle {
  left: 1.6875rem;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.active:before {
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: -0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .75px;
  left: 0.4125rem;
  width: 2.325rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle:before,
.btn-toggle:after {
  color: #6b7381;
}

.btn-toggle.active {
  background-color: #29b5a8;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg:focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:after {
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}


/*.btn-toggle.btn-lg:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: -5rem;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: -5rem;
  opacity: .5;
}*/

.btn-toggle.btn-lg>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3125rem;
  left: 0.3125rem;
  width: 1.875rem;
  height: 1.875rem;
  border-radius: 1.875rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active>.handle {
  left: 2.8125rem;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active:before {
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: 0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .75px;
  left: 0.6875rem;
  width: 3.875rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm {
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  width: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.55rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: -0.5rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: -0.5rem;
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1875rem;
  left: 0.1875rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 1.125rem;
  border-radius: 1.125rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active>.handle {
  left: 1.6875rem;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: -0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .75px;
  left: 0.4125rem;
  width: 2.325rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs:after {
  line-height: 1rem;
  width: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: 0;
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.125rem;
  left: 0.125rem;
  width: 0.75rem;
  height: 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active>.handle {
  left: 1.125rem;
  transition: left .25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active:before {
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: -1rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .75px;
  left: 0.275rem;
  width: 1.55rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary {
  color: #6b7381;
  background: #bdc1c8;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-secondary:after {
  color: #6b7381;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary.active {
  background-color: #ff8300;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary.active {
  background-color: #ff8300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="report-sens-btn btn btn-lg btn-toggle" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="true" autocomplete="off">
<div class="handle"></div>
</button>

<a class="report-action-btn btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-success m-b-5">
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
</a>
```